# PHP Accessing parent class on an include file

Tags: php, class, include

A NEW UPDATE ON THE PROBLEM

I wan't the class 'BlogPost' to access its parent class variables that have been set on the main.php page

```
class BlogPage {
    public $PageExists = false;
    public $PageTitle = "no title";
    public $PageId = "0";
    function __construct($page){
        //some sql to check if page exists
        if($page_exists){
            $this->PageExists = true;
            $this->PageTitle = $fetched['row_title'];
            $this->PageId = $fetched['row_id'];

        }
    }
}

class BlogPost extends BlogPage {
    function __construct(){
        $page_id = $this->PageId;
        //some sql to get the posts that have post_page like $page_id
    }
}
```

The Main.php page

```
$page = new BlogPage("index");
if($page->PageExists == true){
    include("posts.php");
}else{
include("notfound.php");
}
```

The posts.php

```
$pageTitle = $page->PageTitle;
$posts = new BlogPost();
```

?>

Comment: snippet of your code would be great (how are you trying to retreive information from classOne)

Comment: in the 'classTwo' i us $this->varInClassOne or parent::funcInClassOne but that is realy not the point! i tried everything i could find!

Comment: *(sidenote)* regarding `global` keyword: *When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available at that line in the calling file will be available within the called file, from that point forward. However, all functions and classes defined in the included file have the global scope.* - in other words, no need to use `global $classOne` there and in general you want to avoid that keyword anyway when doing OOP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access parent's class `protected` and `public` variables and functions, then you will use the `parent::` static prefix.

In your case, if you want to access `classOne`'s `protected` and `public` variables and functions inside `classTwo`, then you will just use `parent::` inside `classTwo`.

If you just want to use the `classTwo` instantiated object on the included file, then you don't need to declare it as `global`, you just access it normally as you would access it a few lines below declaring it on the main file.

#### Update 1

You don't need to define the scope of that variable as global, because it already has that scope on that part of the script. So, just access it like this:

```
// global $page; remove this, no need for it
$pageTitle = $page->PageTitle;
$posts = new BlogPost();
```

#### Update 2

This is my suggested solution to your second problem:

```
<?php
class Page{
    public $PageExists  = false;
    public $PageTitle   = 'no title';
    public $PageId      = '0';
    // add other options here

    // add other parameters to this function
    // or pass an array to it
    protected function fill($page_id, $page_title){
        $this->PageExists   =   true;
        $this->PageId       =   $page_id;
        $this->PageTitle    =   $page_title;
    }
}

class BlogPage extends Page{
    function __construct($page){
        //some sql to check if page exists
        if($page_exists){
            parent::fill($fetched['row_id'], $fetched['row_title']);
        }
    }
}

class BlogPost extends Page {
    function __construct($page_id){
        //some sql to get the posts that have post_page like $page_id
        if($post_exists){
            parent::fill($fetched['row_id'], $fetched['row_title']);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Then you can use your classes like the following...

On Main.php page

```
<?php
$page = new BlogPage("index");
if($page->PageExists == true){
    include("posts.php");
} else{
    include("notfound.php");
}
?>
```

On posts.php

```
<?php
$pageTitle  = $page->PageTitle;
$posts      = new BlogPost($page->PageId);
?>
```

Comment: @Marc vd M: Then, I have already answered your question my second part of the answer. You don't need to define the scope of that variable as `global`, because it already has that scope on that part of the script. So, just access it like this `$pageTitle = $page->PageTitle;`.

Comment: When i do that i get Trying to get property of non-object in

Comment: @Marc vd M: Maybe your `Trying to get property of non-object in` notice comes from the way you are handling DB connection and record fetching? If you gave us a line as to where it says the problem is, and post us that line, then we would be able to tell you the exact issue.

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in serverpath/posts.php on line 2 - line 2 = $pageTitle = $page->PageTitle;

Comment: @Marc vd M: First of all, what's this `$page_footer = $page->Footer;`, you don't have a `Footer` public variable on `BlogPage` class. Try to comment out that line and see what we have from that.

Comment: sorry but i forgot to delete that from the snippet! that is not it!(tried it tho but same error)

Comment: Of course the `$page->PageTitle` is non-object, it's just an empty variable. The BlogPage object was created in another file, and it doesn't exist in posts.php.

Comment: @joakimdahlstrom i know that. but how do i get in the include file?

Comment: @joakimdahlstrom: _"When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available at that line in the calling file will be available within the called file, from that point forward."_. What you suggest is wrong. The `BlogPage` object was created on the `Main.php` file, which includes `posts.php` file. The included file will inherit all the variables that were available up to the `include("posts.php")` line. The variable `$page` was declared and filled before that line, so, it should be available to `posts.php`.

Comment: @Shef: Absolutely right, I missed that the file was included.

Comment: @Marc vd M: Before you assign the value to `$pageTitle = $page->PageTitle;` add this line `var_dump($page);` and update your question to tell us what it prints.

Comment: @Marc vd M: Then, you are assigning the value `page.php` to the variable `$page` somewhere else. Please do a search for the variable `$page` to check everywhere you are assigning a value to it. Or post the whole code here so we can find it for you. In other words, you are using the same variable name for two different things.

Comment: Sorry, this "Then, you are assigning the value `page.php`" should have read "Then, you are assigning the value `posts.php`".

Comment: Well i found the problem of the $page issue. i ussed a function to include the page dynamicly. when i hard coded to include the page all works fine! The only thing that doesn't work is to access the parent class from the child class that has been created on the include file! i will update my post! I'm half way there!

Comment: Okay, update your question and tell us what you want to do and where. :)

Comment: @Shef Updated! btw u have been verehelpfull so far! if i had more reputation i would gave this post a plus

Comment: @Marc vd M: I see what you want to do... The way you have created your classes you can't use inheritance, because `BlogPost` class does not need ALL of the variables and functions the class `BlogPage` has. Why do you extend the class `BlogPost` with the class `BlogPage`, what are their similarities, what are their differences? I believe you need three classes in this case. Will update my post with a suggested solution to your problem.

Comment: well the BlogPage has the page title,pageid,pageoptions and if set it also says wich header and footer file to use. the options is very important because it contains things like how many posts to show on the page.

Comment: @Marc vd M: What does the `BlogPost` have in common with `BlogPage`?

Comment: the BlogPost gets the pageid from the blogpage, and gets the options of blogpage and do something accordingly!

Comment: @Shef but i guess to question has been awnserd(by you ofcourse) that it is not possible! I guess the solution is to send the $page->Options to the __construct and then handle them! you agree?

Comment: @Marc vd M: Yes, that would be the solution. I just took it a step further to suggest you a better solution for your classes inheritance. Please take a look at update 2.

Comment: @Shef Thanks for the alternative. Solves my problem and is even more efficient. Again much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

I feel that you have your variables in classOne protected

Comment: are you sure that         if($page_exists){
is true?

Comment: yes it is the mysql_num_rows($sql) it is true when there are posts found that match the $PostId. if it where false i would get the page notfound.php

Answer (score 0):

if classTwo extends from classOne you will be able to do:

```
$two = new classTwo();
$two->functionFromClassOne();
```

and have access to the class.

It might be good for you to explain the exact use-case so a best approach can be recommended. Perhaps inheritance isn't the best way of achieving whatever you're trying to build.

Comment: true, i'l post a snippet in a sec